# Change Logging Level of "Executed DBCommand" for EF Core in Azure Function

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-functions

Using Azure Function and Log Stream I'm flooded by these types of logs at the "Information" log level:

```
2023-08-17T21:00:44Z   [Information]   Executed DbCommand (2ms)....
```

How can I change the log level for the executed DbCommand to log under `Trace` instead of `Information` so I'm not flooded w/ these log entries?

I've added the following Configuration -> Application Settings in Azure however I'm still seeing the log entries as Information:

```
Name: AzureFunctionsJobHost__logging__logLevel__Microsoft
Value: Trace
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ConfigureWarnings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder.configurewarnings?view=efcore-7.0) on the context options builder and set the level in [`Log(ValueTuple<EventId,LogLevel>[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.diagnostics.warningsconfigurationbuilder.log?view=efcore-7.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-diagnostics-warningsconfigurationbuilder-log(system-valuetuple((microsoft-extensions-logging-eventid-microsoft-extensions-logging-loglevel))())):

```
services.AddDbContext<AppContext>(builder =>
  builder.Use...(...)
    .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information)
    .ConfigureWarnings(b => b.Log((RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted, LogLevel.Trace)))
);
```

Alternatively you can just use [`Ignore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.diagnostics.warningsconfigurationbuilder.ignore?view=efcore-7.0) to completely disable the event.

Comment: is there any way to do this directly from my configuration settings instead?

Comment: @99823 not that I know of. Usually context is not set up directly via config.