# How to prevent logging all of my Entity Framework SQL queries?

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog, serilog-sinks-file

I'm using `Serilog.Sinks.File` and all of my SQL queries are getting logged.

Here is my configuration code:

```
// Configure Serilog
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
    .WriteTo.File(Path.Combine(applicationContext.GetWorkingPath(), "TrackTrace.WorkerServices.log"),
        rollOnFileSizeLimit: true)
    .CreateLogger();
```

And here is my *appsettings.json*.

```
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Hangfire": "Information",
    "Microsoft": "Warning",
    "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
}
```

With the default Microsoft prefix set to `Warning`, I was expecting that to eliminate all of the SQL queries. What am I missing?

**Update**

Here's how I'm configuring my database.

```
// Configure database
services.AddDbContext<TrackTraceDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(
        connectionString,
        builder => builder.MigrationsAssembly(nameof(TTRailtraxEntities)));
});
```

Comment: And how is the DbContext is registered? Can you provide a [mre] to play with?

Comment: @GuruStron: I've added my code to configure the database. This project has a lot going on so I'm not sure how I'd extract just the necessary parts. I like seeing the SQL queries when debugging. But I would think those are coming from Microsoft and are level Information. So I don't expect to see them here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK Serilog does not use the default configuration section, try moving the setup to Serilog -> MinimumLevel -> Override:

```
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Override": {
            "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Warning"
        }
    },
```

See the [MinimumLevel, LevelSwitches, overrides and dynamic reload](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration#minimumlevel-levelswitches-overrides-and-dynamic-reload) of the docs.

Alternatively you can ignore/change log levels on the context itself on per-event type basis ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76925326/2501279)):

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<TrackTraceDbContext>(b => b.UseSqlServer(...)
    .ConfigureWarnings(w => w.Ignore(RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted)));
```

Or override the logger factory:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<TrackTraceDbContext>(b => b.UseSqlServer(...)
    .UseLoggerFactory(new NullLoggerFactory()));
```

Comment: I was just looking for these log entries... do they look like this in event viewer?: "I/O was resumed on database master. No user action is required."  (sry to add in a question, just curious and wondering whether to remove this logging myself...)

Comment: @pcalkins not sure TBH. Based on quick googling this is some SQL Server specific message, not sure that EF Core even has access/outputs it. Do you have EF Core/ASP.NET Core logging setup to write to event viewer?

Comment: ok, thanks... I just have defaults set... I'll start a new question though.