# EF Core execution time between Console app and Web api

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-7.0

Could anyone explain why there is a huge time execution time between the console application, which takes less than a second to execute, and the API takes minutes. Is it possible to improve ?

I am using .NET 7

Web app

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var cnn = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=EmployeeCacheStore;Mode=Memory;Cache=Shared");
cnn.Open();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(cnn));

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/weatherforecast", (DataContext context1) =>
{
    var time = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
    context1.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
    context1.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

    var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 8000).Select(x => new Record() { Id = x }).ToList();
    context1.Record.AddRange(list);
    context1.SaveChanges();

    return $"Executed in: {Stopwatch.GetElapsedTime(time)}";
}).WithName("GetWeatherForecast");

app.Run();
```

Console:

```
var conn = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=EmployeeCacheStore;Mode=Memory;Cache=Shared");
conn.Open(); 
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext>().UseSqlite(conn).Options;

using (var ctx = new DataContext(options))
{
    var time = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
    ctx.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
    ctx.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 8000).Select(x => new Record() { Id = x }).ToList();
    ctx.Records.AddRange(list);
    ctx.SaveChanges();

    Console.WriteLine("Executed in: {0}", Stopwatch.GetElapsedTime(time));
}
```

Context:

```
public class Record
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}

public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Record> Records { get; set; }

    public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
}
```

Comment: In which order are you running the tests? Web -> Console, or Console -> Web? Are you completely destroying the DB between tests, or are you using TRUNCATE or DELETE [TABLE]? Are the EF generated queries the same? Are the query execution plans the same?  These are some of the questions running through my head.

Comment: I ran them both in two different projects (one after the other), it's memory db so no need to truncate/delete, and it's just an insert. No, I am not "completely destroying" It's only 8k insert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DEBUG:

- Web: Executed in: 00:00:10.0011561
- Console: Executed in: 00:00:00.4682114

In more recent versions of .NET / EF Core, (.NET 6+) EF Logging is configured by default when calling `AddDbContext` or `AddDbContextPool`.

The reason it takes 10 seconds to execute in debug mode because that's how long it takes to write ~24k lines of logging to the console during the execution.

> Initially I thought the Console logging provider.
> Turns out most of the performance impact is coming from the
> [Debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging-providers#debug)
> logging provider.  This is provider only works when the debugger is
> attached, so when you run it in release mode, the execution is
> significantly faster.

You can visualize this by removing logging:

```cs
// this effectively removes all logging providers that were added
// by WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
// making this the same logging setup as the console app.
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();

//builder.Logging.AddConsole(); //uncomment to get log output to the console.
//builder.Logging.AddDebug(); //uncomment to get debug logs while attached to the debugger.  Most performance impact, in this scenario, is here.


//output:
//Web: Executed in: 00:00:00.3051866
//Web (With Console logging): Executed in: 00:00:00.5858375
//Web (With Debug logging): Executed in: 00:00:11.6470355
//Web (With both console and debug): Executed in: 00:00:11.6980340
```

This is not a preferred method for controlling logging for EF Core.

First:
You can control the logging level by configuring the log levels in `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.{Environment}.json` configuration files.

Second:
You can control the logger provider (as pointed out by @Guru Stron) by configuring the options in the context.

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(cnn)
    .UseLoggerFactory(new NullLoggerFactory()));
```

RELEASE:

- Web: Executed in: 00:00:00.5546975
- Console: Executed in: 00:00:00.2601217

Comment: _"is enabled by default in Development."_ - are you sure that it is about development only? Because as far as I can see it does not depend on the environment. Also `builder.Logging.ClearProviders();` is not the best way to handle this (in real-life scenarios).

Comment: we both appear to be slightly wrong here, more updates incoming

Comment: @GuruStron take a look at the updates.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Please check out my answer also, it explains in detail how to deal with EF Core logs.

Comment: I didn't want to steal ALL your thunder. =)

Comment: I'm no Zeus but still have some thunder to share - so please be my guest =)

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that EF Core when run inside ASP.NET Core project by default hooks up to the [`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/#microsoftextensionslogging) infrastructure:

> `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` is an extensible logging mechanism with plug-in providers for many common logging systems. EF Core fully integrates with `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` and this form of logging is used by default for ASP.NET Core applications.

Which results in 8000 messages written to the console/debug in default setup which obviously slows the processing. You can disable logging in EF Core, for example via config (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77002953/how-to-prevent-logging-all-of-my-entity-framework-sql-queries/77003071#77003071)):

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "None"
    }
  }
}
```

Or clearing logger factory:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(cnn)
    .UseLoggerFactory(new NullLoggerFactory()));
```